# How to get alt by the same way?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

That's how other img attributes can be got in the client's theme

```
// Get images attributes
        $images = array();
        foreach ( $galleries as $meta_key => $gallery ) {
            $attachment_ids = array_filter( explode( ',', $gallery ) );
            foreach ( $attachment_ids as $key => $attachment_id ) {
                $full_size_image             = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full' );
                $single                      = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'shop_single' );
                $thumbnail                   = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'shop_thumbnail' );
                $catalog                     = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'shop_catalog' );
                $images[ $meta_key ][ $key ] = array(
                    'single'                  => $single[0],
                    'single_w'                => $single[1],
                    'single_h'                => $single[2],
                    'thumbnail'               => $thumbnail[0],
                    'catalog'                 => $catalog[0],
                    'data-src'                => $full_size_image[0],
                    'data-large_image'        => $full_size_image[0],
                    'data-large_image_width'  => $full_size_image[1],
                    'data-large_image_height' => $full_size_image[2],
                );
            }
        }
```

I need to get and output an alt attribute exactly the same way, how to do it?

```
output_thumb += '<div>';
output_thumb += '<img  width="' + image['single_w'] + '" height="' + image['single_h'] + '" src="' + img_single + '" class="attachment-shop_single size-shop_single" data-src="' + image['data-src'] + '" data-large_image="' + image['data-large_image'] + '" data-large_image_width="' + image['data-large_image_width'] + '" data-large_image_height="' + image['data-large_image_height'] + '"/>';
output_thumb += '</div>';
```

It has to be something like

```
output_thumb += '<div>';
output_thumb += '<img  alt="' + image['alt'] + '"     width="' + image['single_w'] + '" height="' + image['single_h'] + '" src="' + img_single + '" class="attachment-shop_single size-shop_single" data-src="' + image['data-src'] + '" data-large_image="' + image['data-large_image'] + '" data-large_image_width="' + image['data-large_image_width'] + '" data-large_image_height="' + image['data-large_image_height'] + '"/>';
output_thumb += '</div>';
```

Something like

```
var img_alt = $(this).attr('alt'); 

output_thumb += '<img  alt="img_alt"   .....
```

returns alt="img_alt"

Comment: So add a value under an `alt` key in the fist function that fills `$images[ $meta_key ][ $key ]`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution, that I found:

```
// Get default gallery
        $product        = new WC_product( $product_id );
        $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();
        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $product_id ) ) {
            $attachment_ids = $result = array_merge( array( get_post_thumbnail_id( $product_id ) ), $attachment_ids );
        }
        $usedImages = array();
        foreach ( $attachment_ids as $key => $attachment_id ) {
            $full_size_image             = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full' );
            $single                      = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'shop_single' );
            $thumbnail                   = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'shop_thumbnail' );
            $catalog                     = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'shop_catalog' );
            $image_alt = get_post_meta( $attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
            if (!in_array($single[0], $usedImages)) {
                $usedImages[] = $single[0];
                $images['default_gallery'][ $key ] = array(
                    'single'                  => $single[0],
                    'single_w'                => $single[1],
                    'single_h'                => $single[2],
                    'thumbnail'               => $thumbnail[0],
                    'catalog'                 => $catalog[0],
                    'data-src'                => $full_size_image[0],
                    'data-large_image'        => $full_size_image[0],
                    'data-large_image_width'  => $full_size_image[1],
                    'data-large_image_height' => $full_size_image[2],
                    'alt' => $image_alt,
                );
            }
        }

        return $images;
    }
```

```
output_thumb += '<div>';
                                output_thumb += '<img  alt="' + image['alt'] + '"     width="' + image['single_w'] + '" height="' + image['single_h'] + '" src="' + img_single + '" class="attachment-shop_single size-shop_single" data-src="' + image['data-src'] + '" data-large_image="' + image['data-large_image'] + '" data-large_image_width="' + image['data-large_image_width'] + '" data-large_image_height="' + image['data-large_image_height'] + '"/>';
                                output_thumb += '</div>';
```